# read external swf files on sd-card?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating android app. It basically reads external swf files. I can compile the swf files in main app. But the problem is its getting heavier. So I was wondering if I can compile the main app without those swf files and copy those swf files in sd-card and read it from the app. Something like creating files from obb folder like in those big games.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, many 'big data' games are constructed in this way (ex: Machinarium). You even can just create one Main SWF and APK with it and then download all needed SWFs on the first run (or at any time you like), also you can just put these SWFs in some folder put them in APK as related links, both ways are possible.

Comment: can you give any codes to read swf files from sd card ? I've tried it before but it shows errors.

Comment: This might help:
http://developerandroidadobeair.blograby.com/internal-or-external-storage/